# Recap statistic after lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and two different groups - see below.

```
set.seed(123) 
d <- data.frame(
  q1 = rnorm(20),
  q2 = rnorm(20),
  q3 = rnorm(20),
  group = sample(c("A", "B"), size = 20, replace = TRUE))
```

I use `lapply` to calculate the ttest for each column between the two groups as reported below:

```
lapply(d[,-4], function(i) t.test(i ~ d$group))
```

`lapply` returns for each column the results listing several statistical info data (I just reported column q1)

```
$q1

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  i by d$group
t = -0.76262, df = 17.323, p-value = 0.4559
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.2294678  0.5759458
sample estimates:
mean in group A mean in group B 
    -0.05443279      0.27232820
```

I want to recap the main stat info (t, df, pvalue) as single table for each column (q1, q2, q3...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply()` again to extract each parameter and `bind_rows()`:

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(l, function(x) {
  data.frame(t = x$statistic,
             df = x$parameter,
             pv = x$p.value) # returns a dataframe for each element in l
}) %>% bind_rows()

#           t        df         pv
# 1 -1.031983 13.533116 0.32017136
# 2 -2.458574  9.771018 0.03427922
# 3  1.421821 11.416813 0.18181697
```

---

You can do this in one shot:

```
lapply(d[,-4], function(i) {
  res <- t.test(i ~ d$group)
  data.frame(t = res$statistic,
             df = res$parameter,
             pv = res$p.value)
  }) %>% bind_rows()
```

If you want to keep reference to the column names pass `.id` to `bind_rows()`:

```
lapply(d[,-4], function(i) {
  res <- t.test(i ~ d$group)
  data.frame(t = res$statistic,
             df = res$parameter,
             pv = res$p.value)
}) %>% bind_rows(.id='id')
#   id          t       df        pv
# 1 q1 -0.7626249 17.32329 0.4559469
# 2 q2 -1.6467070 17.73117 0.1172263
# 3 q3  0.5288851 13.01589 0.6057874
```

Example:

```
set.seed(123) 
d <- data.frame(
  q1 = rnorm(20),
  q2 = rnorm(20),
  q3 = rnorm(20),
  group = sample(c("A", "B"), size = 20, replace = TRUE))
l <- lapply(d[,-4], function(i) {
  t.test(i ~ d$group)

  })
```

Comment: you can avoid `bind_rows` by using `sapply` ? `data.frame(sapply(d[,-4], function(i) {
  res <- t.test(i ~ d$group);
  c(t = res$statistic,
             df = res$parameter,
             pv = res$p.value)
  
}))`

Comment: Do you know how to report colnames as well?

Comment: Forget that, see my update, there's an `.id` parameter for `bind_rows()`, which gives what you want.